# DropDownCheckBoxes select all issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using Saplin DropDownCheckBoxes but it has select all issue for hat i have write below java script code on Document.ready its working in chrome browser proper with all proper functionality but is wasn't working properly in IE browser please help me in the same

```
<%@ Register Assembly="DropDownCheckBoxes" Namespace="Saplin.Controls" TagPrefix="asp1" %>

  <asp1:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="chkSubClient_Custom" runat="server" AddJQueryReference="true" UseSelectAllNode="true" Width="150px">
  <Style2 SelectBoxWidth="150" /> </asp1:DropDownCheckBoxes>
```

Java Script Code:-

```
        $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
            debugger;
            var Checked = 0;
            var UnChecked = 0;
            var OneUnChecked = 0;
            var Count = 0;


            $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                if (this.name.indexOf("chkSubClient_Custom_sll") > 0) {
                    if (this.checked == true) {
                        Checked = 1;
                    }
                }
            });

            $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                if (Checked == 1) {
                    if (this.name.indexOf("chkSubClient_Custom") > 0) {
                        this.checked = true;
                    }
                }
            });

            $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                if (this.name.indexOf("chkSubClient_Custom_sll") < 0) {
                    if (this.name.indexOf("chkSubClient_Custom") > 0) {
                        if (this.checked == false) {
                            Count = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                if (this.name.indexOf("chkSubClient_Custom_sll") > 0) {
                    if (Count == 0) {
                        this.checked = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: What version of jQuery and what version of IE?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if ($(this).is(':checked'))
{
  // more code
}
```